# asdf fails to download if system is using https_proxy

Tags: asdf-vm

What are some ways to teach asdf to ignore certificate validation or teach it to bypass proxies?

For `curl`, this problem is solved like this:

`$ echo '--proxy ""' >> ~/.curlrc`

OR

`$ echo '-k' >> ~/.curlrc`

OR

`alias curl='curl --proxy ""'`

OR

`alias curl='curl -k ""'`

For `wget` like this:

`$ echo 'use_proxy = off' >> ~/.wgetrc`

OR

`$ echo 'check-certificate = off' >> ~/.wgetrc`

OR

`alias wget="wget --no-check-certificate"`

For `git` like so:

`$ git config --global --add remote.origin.proxy ""`

OR

`$ git config --global http.sslverify false`

But how is this problem solved for `asdf`?

Img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9A1l.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9A1l.png

I tried to specify any of those parameters in the `~/.asdfrc` file that are suitable for `curl`, `wget`, but it does not work.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Additionally I retagged the question to what I think is the correct tag, please undo if that was wrong.